# Use utility test classes under "src/test" from other module in Bazel

Tags: java, maven, bazel

So I'm migrating a multi module project from maven to Bazel and I have encounter the following problem:

I have module A containing some utility test classes under "src/test" and module B using them. In maven, we are generating a *test-jar* using the maven-jar-plugin, which is included from module B as a dependency. But I'm not sure how to migrate this to Bazel.

So far, my bazel config looks like this:

Module B:

```
java_library(
    name = "moduleB-lib",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//path/to/moduleA:lib"
    ],
)


java_library(
    name = "test-dep",
    srcs = glob(["**/src/test/java/**/*.java"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        ":moduleB-lib",
        "@maven:junit-dependencies"
    ],
)

java_test(
    name = "tests",
    args = ["--select-package=org.test"],
    main_class = "org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher",
    use_testrunner = False,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    runtime_deps = [":test-dep"],
)
```

But this is not working since module B is not able to see those utility classes

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the solution, which is quite easy actually:

```
java_library(
    name = "moduleB-lib",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//path/to/moduleA:lib"
    ],
)


java_library(
    name = "test-dep",
    srcs = glob(["**/src/test/java/**/*.java"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        ":moduleB-lib",
        "//path/to/moduleA:test-dep",
        "@maven:junit-dependencies"
    ],
)

java_test(
    name = "tests",
    args = ["--select-package=org.test"],
    main_class = "org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher",
    use_testrunner = False,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    runtime_deps = [":test-dep"],
)
```

To make it work I just added the test-dependencies' java-library from module A.